# How can i fix such bug?

Tags: java, android

My computer froze and after rebooting i opened a studio and project loading tumbled this error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':Application:processDebugResources'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/home/aleksey/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

What does this bug mean? Tell somobody how can i fix it?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Did you try Build > Clean Project, and then Rebuild ?

Comment: Did you do what it says in red, starting it and getting the stack trace, and /or info/debug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

Build -> clean and then Build -> Rebuild Project

or

Upgrade to the latest version of Gradle.